# memory problem with array releasing in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am getting problem with this can any one help me 
here is my code. This code work 1st click but when click 2 time it get error

**malloc:**  error for object 0x4e226a4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to de**bug

```
- (void)updateTextViewContents {
    content = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
    for (int i = 0; i <[ _scoresArray count]; i++)
    {
    NSMutableString *data = [_scoresArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [content appendString:data];
        if([content isEqualToString:UserText.text]&&[content isEqualToString:PassText.text])
        {
        UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Valid User" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alt show];
            [alt release];
            [content release];

        }
        else    
        {
        UIAlertView *alt1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"NOT A Valid User" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alt1 show];
        [alt1 release];
        }
    }
```

**when i release over here it work but when i click 2nd time by entering right user name and password both alter view display at time .I think it will happen because of array get add at every cilck that's why both alter view dispaly at time how i sovle this .**
    //[content release];

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here generate memory problem because of,

you release **content** NSMutableString in if condition and then append it again.

So, Don't release in to for loop, release it out of for loop.

- (void)updateTextViewContents 
{

```
content = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i <[ _scoresArray count]; i++) 
{

    NSMutableString *data = [_scoresArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [content appendString:data];
    if([content isEqualToString:UserText.text]&&[content isEqualToString:PassText.text])
    {
        UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Valid User" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alt show];
        [alt release];
        //[content release]; - Not release here.

    }
    else    
    {
        UIAlertView *alt1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"NOT A Valid User" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alt1 show];
        [alt1 release];
    }
}

[content release];
```

Comment: it work but doesnt show me else alert view when i enter the wrong user and password

Comment: hello, remove the string from content variable instead of release it. For remove the string you can use [content deleteCharactersInRange:((NSRange)range)]; method.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you replace

```
NSMutableString *data = [_scoresArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [content appendString:data];
```

with this

```
    [content appendString:[_scoresArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

your both alert is showing because of your loop put `break` after it is valid user because you must not go through loop after it is valid user
hope this will help
good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have release content in the if condition. For the next iteration you are again trying to append data to content, which is already released if the condition was true in previous iteration. And thus you are getting that error  `object was probably modified after being freed`.